# validate data on dynamic text box at client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am required to make a form in asp.net where I have to use Dynamic text box. 
With some workaround,I managed to create Textboxes when user click "Add" Button and could also retrieve their values (at Server Side).
Now I am facing problem in getting the value at Client side.I want if user click submit without providing any data ,it should not validate the data.

Below is the code in Javascript to create Text boxes I used.

```
 function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
        return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />' +
            '<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" />'
    }
    function AddTextBox() {
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
        document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
    }

    function RemoveTextBox(div) {
        document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
    }

    function RecreateDynamicTextboxes() {
        var values = eval('<%=Values%>');
        if (values != null) {
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBox(values[i]) + "</div>";
            }
            document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML = html;
        }
    }
```

This code is executed when ADD button is clicked.

```
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox()" class="ANPClass"/>
```

and TextBoxContainer is just an DIV

```
<div id="TextBoxContainer" style="text-align: center;" class="step" >
</div>
```

**Scenario**
If user click on radio button,he gets a button "ADD" clicking on which ,he can generate dynamic text box.If he clicks and do not provide value,then in my sql,i will get value as "" (that is Ok) but if he click on radio button and without clicking ADD button,submits the form ,I get NULLVALUE exception,

So basically I want to capture the dynamic text box data on Client Side so that I can validate the data and display error message is value is blank.

Should I think of events or what.Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: At what point of time you want to validate dynamic textboxes?

Comment: And where is "TextBoxContainer" html is above code

Comment: @AmitSoni-Its just DIV .I added that code too.

Answer (score 0):

check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/pqv5gauz/) where added your code fiddler.

```
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddTextBox()" class="ANPClass"/>
<div id="TextBoxContainer" style="text-align: center;" class="step" >
</div>
<input type="button" value="save" onclick="validate();" />
```

Javascript

```
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
        return '<input name = "DynamicTextBox" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />' +
            '<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" />'
    }
function validate()
{
    var inp = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i in inp){
        if(inp[i].type == "text"){
            if(!/^\d{1,}$/.test(inp[i].value)){
                alert('Invalid value detected');
                inp[i].focus();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

function AddTextBox() {
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
        document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
    }

    function RemoveTextBox(div) {
        document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
    }

    function RecreateDynamicTextboxes() {
        var values = eval('<%=Values%>');
        if (values != null) {
            var html = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBox(values[i]) + "</div>";
            }
            document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML = html;
        }
    }
```

check this modified code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pqv5gauz/2/)

added class in input

> class="dynamic"

and javascript code

> var inp = document.getElementsByClassName('dynamic');

```
function validate()
{
    var inp = document.getElementsByClassName('dynamic');
    for(var i in inp){

        if(inp[i].type == "text"){
            if(!/^\d{1,}$/.test(inp[i].value)){
                alert('Invalid value detected');
                inp[i].focus();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but then it will find all other everyother textbox in page.i gave only a small portion of code.It contains many other textbox.

Comment: @vish check modfied code. i have added JSfiddler link at the end.

Comment: Thanks but still not working...Its still undefined.i will try something with hidden fields

Comment: @vish did you checked in fiddler? it's working there..  have you added class in input?

Comment: yes,I added.also in fiddler,it is showing invalid data in all cases (i.e With data and without data.) .What if user click on save without clicking on ADD button,then also it should have some notification type so that validation can be done.I am also trying,..well great thanks for your help